# Display: flex and justify-content: space-between always leaves uneven space at the right and left margin

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a course about web development and I'm a complete newbie so please don't judge me. I have an assignment where I need to recreate a screenshot of a page. I'm having problems at pushing the divs from the footer to the left and right and for them to have equal space between the div and the edge of the screen. This should be [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgjan.png), and this is [what I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2LMr.png).

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

img {
  width: 600px;
}
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
button {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #eee;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

.header{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.left-links{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 10px;
}
.right-links{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 10px;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.content{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}
.footer{
  display: flex;
  background-color: gainsboro;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>LAYOUT</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <ul class="left-links">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="right-links">
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="./logo.png" alt="Project logo. Represents odin with the project name.">
      <div class="input">
        <input type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>Do the thing!</button>
        <button>Do the other thing!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <ul class="left-links">
        <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="right-links">
        <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried to do it either with `justify-content: space-between` and I was thinking about using the `flex-start` and `flex-end` attributes too but these don't work.

Comment: <ul>s have some default padding, you may want to remove it.

Comment: yes, i've seen that too but i dont know how to remove it

Comment: Additionally, you should remove `body {overflow: hidden;}` because it cuts off the page in short viewports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ul>`s have default padding. Just reset it to `10px` in both sides for the `<ul>` of `.header` and `.footer` classes.

```
.header ul, .footer ul{
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');

body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

img {
    width: 600px;
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
button {
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    border: none;
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #eee;
}

input {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 16px;
    padding: 8px 24px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    background-color: gainsboro;
}

.header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.left-links{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 10px;
}
.right-links{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 10px;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
}
.footer{
    display: flex;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header ul, .footer ul{
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>LAYOUT</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <ul class="left-links">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="right-links">
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://www.theodinproject.com/assets/og-logo-022832d4cefeec1d5266237be260192f5980f9bcbf1c9ca151b358f0ce1fd2df.png" alt="Project logo. Represents odin with the project name.">
      <div class="input">
        <input type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>Do the thing!</button>
        <button>Do the other thing!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <ul class="left-links">
        <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="right-links">
        <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the padding of ul elements inside footer and add some padding to the .footer try this:

```
.footer{
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding: 0.7rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: gainsboro;
}
.footer ul{
  padding: 0;
}
```